# Reputation league inconsistencies(/lag?)

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-leagues

According to the [Gaming reputation league](https://web.archive.org/web/20170814150110/https://stackexchange.com/leagues/7/quarter/gaming/2017-07-01/171580) I'm in 11th place with 759 total reputation and 709 quarter reputation. But in reality I have [779 reputation](https://web.archive.org/web/20170814150257/https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/171580/fabian?tab=reputation). This could be due to a delayed update of the league (it was correct until 3 hours ago), but it also says that my quarter reputation is 709, which I can't understand. If it counts the last 3*30 days or so, it's way off, so I assume that it counts from 1st of July until 30th of September. But in this time my reputation went up 725 points, not 709. Even with the delayed update, it's still not correct, then it should be 705, not 709.

So: Is there a bug or am I missing something?

([Quick link to my rep history](https://stackexchange.com/users/7651254/fabian?tab=reputation))

Comment: Reputation leagues are updated once every day, I think at 3 AM UTC.

Comment: Correct, that explains it. I downvoted 4 times in that time frame, together with the daily updates the number is correct.

Comment: My comment was a response to a now deleted comment linking to the question this was resolved as a duplicate of.